# How to prevent lxml from changing empty elements when writing to file?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml

Python lxml write is converting tag. Say:

```
<p name="Param"></p>
```

To

```
<p name="param"/>
```

My write method call is something like this:

```
treeobj.write('XYZ.xml', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8")
```

I am having:

Python 3.7 and lxml==4.2.5

Now I don't want lxml write to change that. how can i prevent this ?

Comment: You could try to use the `method="html"` argument to `write()`.

Comment: Well with `method="html"` works but it again adds `</p>` where its not there. Say Original : `<p name="param"/>` to `<p name="param"/></p>`. I don't want lxml to modify the given XML.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to tell lxml "don't change empty elements; keep the syntax exactly as it is in the input document".